# How insert span into image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My goal is insert `<span>` into `<image>`, but I don't know how. Similar effect is on page http://www.bulb.cz/cs/reference, but I don't want it on `hover()` but on `click()`. I want insert "data-title" into `<span>` and after that `<span>` show on `<image>`.

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="Fotogalery">   
 <img src="images/Thumb/1.jpg" data-title="Zdar"  /> 
 <img src="images/Thumb/2.jpg" data-title="Ahoj" />
 <img src="images/Thumb/3.jpg"  data-title="Cau"  />
 <img src="images/Thumb/4.jpg" data-title="KUK" />  
 <img src="images/Thumb/5.jpg" data-title="ohh" />  
 </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.Foto{width: 25%;height:auto;float:left;box-sizing: border-box;}
.Gallery{position:relative;}
.Gallery span{position:absolute;z-index:999;}
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(".Fotogalery img").addClass("Foto");
$(".Foto").wrap( "<div class='Gallery'></div>" );
$(".Foto").after("<span></span>");
$(".Foto").click(function() {
    var a = $(this).data('title');
});
```

Comment: Sorry, it is unclear what you ask. You cannot insert a html span tag into an image. Please use the `edit` button right below your question and add more details to add. Try to explain what it is you want to do. Not by technical terms, but your motivation and goal.

Comment: What you're asking for is to position a `<span>` **over** the centre of an `<img>` after a click (and probably hide it on a second click)

Comment: exactly. How write "yuk", but problem is when i click on image, span show me in secondary image, and when i click on fourth span show me totaly out of image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this — http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/p72jnbLt/5/:

**Javascript:**

```
$('.Fotogalery img').addClass('Foto');
$('.Foto').wrap('<div class="Gallery"></div>');
$('.Foto').click(function () {
    var a = $(this).data('title');
    $(this).after('<span>' + a + '</span>');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.Fotogalery {
    font-size: 0;
}

.Foto {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.Gallery {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 25%;
}

.Gallery span {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Comment: problem is everything is in first image :/

Comment: It works good but problem is with viewing When i use float:left in .Gallery postimg.org/image/8oj4u9bav and without float:left in .Gallery postimg.org/image/zbhvmzluj

Comment: Updated answer, check out.

Comment: If you want to use `float: left`, you should to use fixed `width` and `height` for image/container.

Comment: Really thanks a lot, but pls can you say me how it works ? Why .Gallery and .Foto need display: inline-block and without 
.Fotogalery {font-size: 0;} it doesnt work ?

Comment: `display: inline-block` allows fit your image in 25% of `.Fotogalery` width. But when you `display: inline-block`, you have unnecessary extra space between elements, `font-size: 0` allows avoid it, read article about it — https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right, u can use next('span') to select span:

```
     $(".Foto").click(function() {
        var a = $(this).data('title');
        $(this).next('span').html(a);
  })
```

To have span floating over image, make span `position:absolute`, and container `postion:relative`

http://jsfiddle.net/gbg1vfLb/2/

Comment: yuk, you have totaly right, but problem is when i click on image, span show me in secondary image, and when i click on fourth span show me totaly out of image

Comment: It works good but problem is with viewing
When i use float:left in .Gallery 
http://postimg.org/image/8oj4u9bav/

and without float:left in .Gallery 
http://postimg.org/image/zbhvmzluj/